# JAVA GUI application on Raspberry Pi with touch screen

Tags: raspbian, java

I am absolutely new to Raspberry Pi. But I want to use it for one of my project requirements.

I have developed a Java Swing GUI with NetBeans (using third party libraries RxTx, jFreeChart, Dynamic Reports). The GUI connects to serial port via USB (UART), to my microcontroller device which controls a Motor and takes sensor readings. Hence the user can control the motor and take sensor readings via this GUI interface. Then the user clicks 'Plot' button on the GUI which fetches the sensor readings to laptop and plots the sensor reading on jPanel of the GUI as jLineChart. There is another button 'Generate Report' which exports this sensor reading plot to a `report.pdf` file storing it at particular location creating a new directory for that day. The PDF report generation uses DynamicReports library. This application works fine and is my first stage of development.

Now in second stage of development I want to remove the use of laptop where the GUI runs, rather I want to use standalone device which can run the application just like a laptop. Here I want to use Raspberry Pi where a 7-inch touch screen LCD will show the GUI and perform all the tasks (it used to perform on my laptop) i.e. fetching the readings, plotting and generating and storing `report.pdf` on my Raspberry Pi device.

Want to know from you experts, Is this porting of application and interfacing with touch screen LCD feasible with Raspberry Pi? Also I would like to mail the report over Wi-Fi or Ethernet internet.

If yes, could you please let me know which LCD touchscreen I can use for my purpose? And some reference materials to port my java GUI application to Raspberry Pi and also for Wi-Fi.

Comment: http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/~/category/id=3094861&inview=product14647624&offset=0&sort=priceAsc 
This is a product that has been designed for the Pi. There have been projects where people have turned these into a 'tablet' like device, powered from a 5v battery. If portability is required, it's always an option.

Comment: Gaurav,
hava you run your java app with the touch screen? Which product finally?
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

WRT "porting" the java stuff, you shouldn't have to do much beyond, of course, installing java.   There are, I think, openJDK 7 packages in raspbian, and there's a [preview release](http://jdk8.java.net/fxarmpreview/) of oracle 8 made with hard float for arm which works on the pi.  I have not tried swing stuff with it but I would presume that it is there.

The foundation of the linux GUI is the Xorg server.  By default raspbian includes a light weight simple "desktop environment" (LXDE) on top of Xorg; you can run your app from there or you can run it stand-alone (ie, it would be the only application and there would be nothing else to the desktop).

Comment: "There are, I think, openJDK 7 packages in raspbian" There are, but may want to use regular debian, as the Oracle JDK does not run on armhf, only on armel.